# Good synonyms for "waste of time"?

Tags: american-english, synonyms, british-english

Can't think of any off the top of my head, and the thesaurus comes up with bland results.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate added information about your question, such as the context of your question, what you have found (or what confused you) when you researched the answer, etc. With more information, you're more likely to get a more helpful answer.

Comment: What's the problem with the question?

Comment: Please specify what those "bland results" were, or you're just likely to get the same ones again.

Answer (score 4):

A [timesink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timesink) (or [here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/T/time-sink.html)). Also sometimes, time-drain or even time-waster.

**Futility** - *n.* the quality of being futile; ineffectiveness; uselessness.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this just came up today in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143959/word-choices-in-spartacus-series/143993#143993).

There's a fun pair "tarry" and "dally". They both mean to purposely spend more time than necessary doing something. However, "tarry" is a positive way of saying it, and "dally" is a negative way.

Given how our culture is about "wasting time" these days, you don't hear "tarry" much anymore, which is kind of sad. It does appear in one of my favorite hymns though: [In The Garden](http://www.hymntime.com/tch/htm/i/t/g/itgarden.htm).

> ```
> And He walks with me, and He talks with me,
> And He tells me I am His own;
> And the joy we share as we tarry there,
> None other has ever known.
> ```

Comment: One phrase which I've seen increasingly amongst programmers is "yak shaving" - which refers to work which is done purportedly to save time/effort in the long run, but perhaps also as a form of procrastination.

Comment: My wife and I stayed at a bed and breakfast in New York State (Salamanca) recently called "The Tarry Inn." By the way, to tarry with the Lord in the garden would not be a waste of time, agreed?  Don

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [site](http://thesaurus.com/browse/waste+of+time?__utma=1.1430183046.1388508191.1388542311.1388582363.7&__utmb=1.6.8.1388582749644&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1388528496.3.2.utmcsr=dictionary.reference.com%7Cutmccn=%28referral%29%7Cutmcmd=referral%7Cutmcct=/browse/diaspora&__utmv=-&__utmk=177183781). I have a feeling, however, you're looking for something different, but then again, maybe not. I like *snipe hunt*.